# Realm: Writing into a nested schema

Tags: react-native, realm, realm-list

I have a model that has a lot of nested lists (Example will be below).  I am having issues figuring out how to write into these nested lists.

```
const examSchema = {
  name: 'Exams',
  properties: {
    Exams: { type: 'list', objectType: 'ExamList' },
  },
};

const examList = {
  name: 'ExamList',
  properties: {
    creationDateTime: 'date',
    SITE: 'string',
    examCodeList: { type: 'list', objectType: 'ExamCodeList' },
  },
};

const examCodeList = {
  name: 'ExamCodeList',
  properties: {
    EXAMCODE: 'string',
    DESCRIPTION: 'string',
    SUBEXAMS: { type: 'list', objectType: 'SubExamCodeList' },
  },
};

const subExamCodeList = {
  name: 'SubExamCodeList',
  properties: {
    DESCRIPTION: 'string',
    EXAMCODE: 'string',
    SUBSUBEXAM: { type: 'list', objectType: 'SubSubExamCodeList' },
  },
};

const subSubExamCodeList = {
  name: 'SubSubExamCodeList',
  properties: {
    DESCRIPTION: 'string',
    EXAMCODE: 'string',
  },
};
```

The schema should match this JSON Schema:

```
"Exams": [{
    "creationDateTime": "2017-01-24T09:29:51-05:00",
    "SITE": "SCH",
    "examCodeList": [{
      "EXAMCODE": "VEHICLE",
      "DESCRIPTION": "GE Vehicle Failures",
      "SUBEXAM": [{
        "DESCRIPTION": "WILL NOT START",
        "EXAMCODE": "NOSTART",
        "SUBSUBEXAM": [{
          "DESCRIPTION": "FEEDER/SUPPLY FAULT",
          "EXAMCODE": "FEEDER"
        },{
          "DESCRIPTION": "LOCAL SWITCH FAILURE",
          "EXAMCODE": "LOCSWTC"
        },{
          "DESCRIPTION": "INHIBIT BY LOGIC CIRCUIT",
          "EXAMCODE": "INHIBIT"
        }]
      }]
    }]
  }]
```

Then the write function I have created looks like this.

```
let test;
realm.write(() => {
  test = realm.create('Exams', {});
});

test.Exams.push({
  creationDateTime: new date(2017, 01, 20),
  SITE: 'SCH1',
});

test.Exams.examCodeList.push({
  EXAMCODE: 'example',
  DESCRIPTION: 'example',
});

test.Exams.examCodeList.SUBEXAMS.push({
  DESCRIPTION: 'example',
  EXAMCODE: 'example',
});

test.Exams.examCodeList.SUBEXAMS.SUBSUBEXAM.push({
  DESCRIPTION: 'example',
  EXAMCODE: 'example',
});
```

I know there has got to be a better way to do this, but I am not finding anything online on how to write to a nested list schema. Thanks for the help!

Comment: It is possible to feed `Realm.create` an entire object hierarchy, similar to the JSON you have. Try calling `realm.create('Exams', json)`, where `json` is the parsed JSON string of your data. Keep in mind that `date` fields like `creationDateTime` will have to be converted to JavaScript Dates from the original string values.